# End of Fourth Hour Approaching, Berachot of Keriyat Shema or Amidah?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, bircas-krias-shema

- According to general halacha, one may not recite the *berachot of
  keriyat shema* after the 4th halachic hour. Ashkenazim can do so if
  they were withheld from reciting them in their proper time for
  reasons outside one's control (*ones*)<sup>1</sup>, and sefardim can
  do so without *shem umalchut*<sup>2</sup>.
- Another halacha is that one should ideally say the important *shemona
  esre* before the 4th hour is over (i.e. be finished saying it by
  then)<sup>3</sup>.

**Imagine the scenario that someone realises they only have 8 minutes left until the end of the 4th halachic hour, which is *either* enough time to recite the *berachot of keriyat shema* *or* say *shemone esre* (and in either case be finished by the end of the 4th hour), but they *can't* do both.**

### What should this person do?

---

After the 4th hour, they can't recite the *berachot of keriyat shema* at all (let's assume it's not *ones*, and be able to answer for sefardim as well as ashkenazim), but there is an opinion (the Rabbis - see Berachot 26a), as well as other provisions to say *shemone esre* up to *chatzot* (halachic midday), which one might be allowed to rely on in this case. Or one might argue that none of the above would apply in this case, and therefore the question becomes what is more important, *berachot of keriyat shema*, or *shemone esre*? Maybe the argument is that one is still before the 4th halachic hour is over, so one should endeavour to follow standard procedure.

I note that I am uncertain if, a few minutes before the 4th hour ends, one is allowed to *start* berachot of keriyat shema if one isn't going to be able to *finish* them by the time the 4th hour ends. That might be pertinent to answering this as well.

Thank you everyone for considering this question.

---

<sup>1 - Mishkanot Yacov O'C 80 states they can say the berachot even until chatzot, and Mishna Berura 71:4 and Beiur Halacha 58:6 says you can rely on this. This may complicate this question.</sup>
<sup>2 - Shulchan Aruch O.C. 58:6, Or Letzion 2:6:4, Yalkut Yosef 89:5</sup>
<sup>3 - Rif 18a, Rosh 4:1, and Rambam (Tefillah 3:1), Tur and Shulchan Aruch 89:1</sup>

Comment: Another possibly relevant consideration: reciting birchot keriat shema allows you to be masmich geulah letefillah

Comment: @JoelK very good point. Reminds me of my second story in this question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/132767/if-one-wishes-to-take-on-chumrot-or-segulot-or-mystical-practices-to-what-ext

Comment: https://din.org.il/2015/02/07/%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A3-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%95-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2/

Comment: The notion that someone could time the end of the fourth hour so precisely for this to really matter is fanciful at best https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13226/759

Comment: @JoelK That would only possibly justify starting "emet veyatziv..." before the amida.

Comment: @DoubleAA Assume not within arctic circle, using a time calculated by the Rabbonim of one's city (who account for as many variances as possible), and even accepting atmospheric variance, I don't think this question is fanciful. Given that S'A takes at least 3 minutes, and B'KS takes at least 8, this dilemma is still possible without leaning on leniencies. I know this question is a bit cringe, and people shouldn't be in this situation in the first place etc.

Comment: In a case of *aninut* ending towards the end of the fourth hour, MB 71:4 quotes from Derech HaChaim to say *birchot keriat shema*, even if that means saying *amidah* after the fourth hour finishes.

Comment: Another option might be to skip all the parts that aren’t מעכב/essential (see Mishnah Berurah 66:53 and 68:1)

Comment: @RabbiKaii The notion that Rabbonim of one's city could calculate the end of the fourth hour so precisely for this to really matter is fanciful at best.

Comment: @DoubleAA why? the only truly unknown is atmospheric conditions, and that leads to a variance of 2 minutes according to this answer in the question you linked above: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13241/31534. Your main link in your question is broken so I have no way to evaluate your statement of "fanciful at best".

Comment: @RabbiKaii There's also elevation and obstructions on the horizon, which are virtually never accounted for at all, let alone precisely as if anyone knows what the correct halachic way to account for them is, not to mention all the halachic sfeikot about when exactly the beginning and end of the 12 hours is.

Comment: @DoubleAA ok I'll take your word for it. I didn't realise there was uncertainty in how to account for elevation and obstruction (I knew there was machlokes).

Comment: I believe the Shulchan Aruch and others treat birkot shma as part of tefilah, which raises several relevant questions: (1) are you even allowed to skip birkot KS to get to the amidah at shacharit if the clock is running out? (2) according to those who say if you start b'zman you're OK, would saying birkot kriat shma count as "starting" tefilah?